# Application of rook polynomials (GFs) to pairing problem.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

There has to be a way to use rook polynomials to solve [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1234696/521868):

> How do I find the number of ways 8 people can be formed into pairs with the constraint that they cannot work with the same person they worked with [on a previous] project?

The restricted cells on the board would naturally be the diagonal (participants cannot be paired with themselves), as well as the cells corresponding to the pairings in the first project.

There are $105$ possible pairs of $8$ people.

In addition, the pairs of participants force symmetry along the diagonal.

The calculus of the coefficients is probably in the [sequence AO54479 - OEIS](https://oeis.org/A054479) as noted in one of the answers. However, I would like to see how these coefficients can be built up from the ground up.

Comment: It doesn't seem like A054479 is the correct sequence because this counts "the number of *ordered pairs of disjoint perfect matchings* in the complete graph on $2n$ vertices". It is more likely you want [A053871](https://oeis.org/A053871) then multiply by the number of ways to assign $n$ tasks to pairs: $n!$. You can convince yourself that A054479 is not right as manual counting for $n=2$ yields only $2$ valid matchings (as in A053871) then there are $2!$ ways to assign tasks. That's $2\times 2!=4$ assignments, *not* $6$ or any multiple thereof.

Comment: @N.Shales Thank you. Beyond this particular case, how do you identify the right sequence? Do you know them through familiarity and use, or is there a system?

Comment: I knew a couple of similar generating functions already so I have an idea of how these are found, I couldn't get the generating function for A054479 using the question description so I searched the cross-references and found one which did match my generating function (A053871). The only difference being the factor of $n!$.

Comment: Additionally I wouldn't use rook polynomials here (although you might be able to). I think probably the simplest way to count here is to use inclusion-exclusion directly by forming sets $A_k$ of matchings where person $k$ *is* matched with their original partner $n+k$ then $|A_{k_1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{k_r}|=(2(n-r)-1)!!$ is the number of matchings of the remaining $n-r$ pairs. By inclusion-exclusion the number of desired matchings is $$M_n=\sum_{r=0}^{n}(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}(2(n-r)-1)!!$$ and the number of desired assignments is $M_nn!$.